# How to Edit FileGDB attribute using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am able to attach a file GDB in QGIS (version 1.9). But I cann't edit it's content available in attribute table and 'Toggle editing mode' button was also disabled in Attribute table. Does anyone knows how to edit FileGDB attributes using attribute Table ?